# Editor de texto geany

Tags: python, geany

Estou usando o geany para programação em python e preciso trocar a cor do fundo do editor de texto, estou usando ele no debian alguém sabe como fazer?
[image: queria algo assim]

Comment: Já tentou entrar em Preferências?

Comment: Sim já, mas não consegui nada por lá.

Comment: Valeu amigo valeu ficou show agora.

Answer (score 1):

Siga os passos:

1. Clique no menu Editar > Preferências (ou tecle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
2. No menu Editor vá a aba Exibição e desmarque o checkbox "Inverter as cores da destacação sintática"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O editor ficará com o fundo branco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: ... não deixe de marcar ✔️ na resposta! ObG!

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi, tem que marcar como resolvido?

Comment: Sim. Clique no icone  ✔️ ao lado da resposta. É assim que funciona quando vc tem uma resposta q resolveu sua pergunta.